# How can I add type to a variable defined in a for with typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, casting

I am working in a project with angular 2 & cli and I am trying to iterate over an array of objects, it would be something like

```
    for (let element of this.elements) {
```

However, it doesn't compile because later I need to access to one of the element's property. I suppose, I should cast & typing the var element saying explicitly it is an object

Therefore, I have tried

```
    for (let element : Object of this.elements) {
```

But, it doesn't work.

Comment: the type is going to be whatever the type the array is made of. If elements is string[] then the type of element is string.

Comment: The type of `element` is inherited from the type of the array `this.elements`

Comment: the question is what exactly is `element`? console.log and see if it turns out to be what you expect. also what is the error thrown?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that the type of it is inherited to elements, anyway I can't access to a property of element so I suppose I would need to create an interface

Comment: Sorry, why did I get -1? Very surprised, honestly I think it can help a lot of people. I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use types in that specific context, the type of element is inherited from whatever the type of this.elements is as follows:

```
type TestType = {
    hello: string;
    world: number;
}

class Sample {
    public elements: TestType[];

    constructor() {
        for (let element of this.elements) {
            // Element is of type TestType
        }
    }
}
```

You can try to **cast** it to something else though:

```
type TestType = {
    hello: string;
    world: number;
}

class Sample {
    public elements: TestType[];

    constructor() {
        for (let element of (this.elements as Object[])) {
            // Element is now of type Object
        }
    }
}
```

Same concept applies to interfaces.